# Javascript confirm box works in Chrome but not in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

The following javascript works fine in chrome but not in firefox or IE,
In my case, I'm executing something in jQuery ajax and that ajax executed file will echo this code to browser.

```
<script> 
 var con=confirm("Well Done, You have made a new sale. Click OK to proceed");
 if(con==true) {
  window.location.href="sales_supervisor.php"; 
 } 
 else 
 { 
  return false; 
 } 
</script>
```

It is working fine in chrome, but not working in firefox and IE.

Comment: you can just do `if(con){...}` since `con` is already either true or false as a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

remove the else condition , since return should be used only in functions...